# sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode: incorrect when using UILineBreakModeClip?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm having a bit of trouble with sizeWithFont, in particular with the lineBreakMode.

```
CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(30, 999);
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"TrebuchetMS" size:10.0f];
CGSize size = [@"hello" sizeWithFont: font constrainedToSize:maxSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeClip];
```

With this code, size comes back with a width of 23 and a height of 13, which is correct, however if I reduce the maxSize to (10, 999) the size that returns ends up with a width of 9 and a height of 39, as if the text has been wrapped onto multiple lines. Shouldn't UILineBreakModeClip have resulted in the height remaining the same as it was initially (with the rest of the line just being clipped) or is my understanding of this a bit off?

Answer (score 0):

sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode: is intended to calculate multiple lines of text, so it breaks the text onto multiple lines to try and make it fit within the given width. Instead, try sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode: which is meant to computer a single line of text.

See the [UIKit NSString Additions Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html) for info.